# How to implement the Comparator for the super class and sub class in java

Tags: java, comparator

I am having super class(**ArticleSummary**) and sub class(**Article**).

In controller I am getting the list of type **ArticleSummary** .

My Requirement is I want to sort the list with some properties(say **id**) belongs to ArticleSummary and some properties (say **date,status**...) belongs to Article.

Can any body suggest how can I achieve this requirement.

I want to go with using **comparator** or else is there any best way in java for this requirement.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What is your question? Any code you have?

Comment: If it is of type `Article` anyways, why not cast it to the same?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a list of `ArticleSummary` objects, you cannot access `Article` fields. If your list actually contains `Article` objects, then implementing `compareTo` in the Article class and comparing by `super.id` should work.

Just remember `Article` is an `ArticleSummary`, but `ArticleSummary`s are not `Article`s

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the Comparable interface (see below), then when you have your `list` of `ArticleSummary` objects, you can sort it with `Collections.sort(list);`

Here the code to implement the interface:

```
class ArticleSummary implements Comparable<ArticleSummary> {

    @Override
    public int compareTo(ArticleSummary o) {
        //here this is of class ArticleSummary
        //so you can compare only fields of the class ArticleSummary
        //no matter what object o is
        return 0;
    }
}

class Article extends ArticleSummary {

    @Override
    public int compareTo(ArticleSummary o) {
        if (o instanceof Article) {
            //here both this and o are of class Article
            //so you can compare fields of both classes ArticleSummary and Article
            Article otherArticle = (Article) o; //to use other object as an Article
            return 0;
        } else {
            //here this is of class Article but o is of class ArticleSummary
            //therefore you can only compare fields of class ArticleSummary
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```